# Putting a background under a frameset

Tags: html, css, styles, frames, frameset

What I am trying to do is probably very simple. I currently have frames in my index.html. I have a top, left, right bottom and center frame. This makes my page look pretty awkward. Here is my index.html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Support Portal</title>
    </head>
    <frameset rows="28,*,5" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
        <frame name="topNav" src="top_nav.html" scrolling="no" noresize>
    <frameset cols="110,*,110" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
        <frame name="menu" src="menu_1.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize>
        <frame name="content" src="content.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize>
        <frame name="related" src="related.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize>
    </frameset>
        <frame name="footer" src="footer.html">
    <noframes>
    <p>This section (everything between the 'noframes' tags) will only be displayed if the users' browser doesn't support frames. You can provide a link to a non-frames version of the website here. Feel free to use HTML tags within this section.</p>
    </noframes>

    </frameset>
    </html>
```

What I was hoping to do was take my 'content.html' and all of my other html files and make the background-color transparent, and then put a background image behind everything so the page would look more like 1 page, instead of 5 put together. Here is the top of my content page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family:Ubuntu, sans-serif;
        font-size:10pt;
        margin:10px;
        background-color:transparent;
        }
    a {
        color:white;
        }
```

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, with frames, each document is separate and nothing else is allowed (mostly, the code at the bottom may work in some browsers...) You could kind of hack it in like so:

In css for top_nav.html:

```
body {
    background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

In css for menu_1.html:

```
body {
    background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -28px 0;
}
```

In css for content.html:

```
body {
    background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -28px -110px;
}
```

In css for related.html:

```
body {
    background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -28px right;
    /* this may not work as the image may be too big... */
}
```

In css for footer.html:

```
body {
    background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom 0;
    /* this may not work as the image may be too tall... */
}
```

That will be the solution to most likely work across browsers... however, I think the following works in some browsers.

```
frameset {
    background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: All answers were right: This is not the way I should be doing this. Your answer was pretty unique/interesting though. Thanks, Cheers, and +1.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use frames at all. It's old and not reliable. What you should use is divs. If you want only one part of the page to change, you can use javascript and jQuery.

When using divs, you can use `background` property in CSS to manipulate the background of specific element, e.g.:

```
background-color: #FFF;
```

You also should use a seperate CSS file and link to it in the head tag (BEFORE any javascript file):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Comment: The "You shouldn't use frames at all. It's old and not reliable." comment requires elaboration so as not to be misleading. Everything lends itself better to some purposes more than others.

Answer (score 0):

The modern way of doing what you are trying to do, is with Javascript.
You want to have many static pages and built a web site with out having to edit 10 pages every time you want to add something on the menu for example.

I don't agree with you but anyway, you are looking for Ajax content load (you load your pages into one).

Or you can built your main page layout and then put iframes with can have the pages background.

I realy dont think that you should do tha but...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Support Portal</title>
        <style>
            body{
                /*background-image here*/
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px;">
            <iframe name="topNav" src="top_nav.html" scrolling="no" style="border:0px;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;height:28px;"></iframe>
            <div style="position:absolute;top:28px;bottom:5px;left:0px;right:0px;">
                <div style="position:relative;height:100%;width:100%;">
                    <iframe name="menu" src="menu_1.html" scrolling="no" style="border:0px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;bottom:0px;width:110px;height:100%;"></iframe>
                    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:110px;right:110px;bottom:0px;">
                        <iframe name="content" src="content.html" scrolling="no" style="border:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <iframe name="related" src="related.html" scrolling="no" style="border:0px;position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;width:110px;height:100%;"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <iframe name="footer" src="footer.html" scrolling="no" border="0" style="border:0px;width:100%;position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px;height:5px;"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is working

Answer (score 0):

Try  it works for me

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Support Portal</title>
    <style>
        HTML{
            /*background-image here*/
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px;">
        <iframe name="topNav" src="top_nav.html" scrolling="no" style="border:0px;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;height:28px;"></iframe>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:28px;bottom:5px;left:0px;right:0px;">
            <div style="position:relative;height:100%;width:100%;">
                <iframe name="menu" src="menu_1.html" scrolling="no" style="border:0px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;bottom:0px;width:110px;height:100%;"></iframe>
                <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:110px;right:110px;bottom:0px;">
                    <iframe name="content" src="content.html" scrolling="no" style="border:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
                </div>
                <iframe name="related" src="related.html" scrolling="no" style="border:0px;position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;width:110px;height:100%;"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <iframe name="footer" src="footer.html" scrolling="no" border="0" style="border:0px;width:100%;position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px;height:5px;"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation. With older questions like this one, particularly with accepted answers, it is useful to explain how your answer differs from the exiting answers, or what new information it brings to the question.

Comment: @feckie - I'm glad you somehow found your way to this old post, but I think the general consensus is that iframes are deprecated. If iframes are needed, this issue should be solved with JS or CSS hacks.